# T32api to click a button in a dialog box

Tags: lauterbach

I am trying to click a button of an already opened dialog box using the t32api.T32_Cmd() function.
But I am not able to find a suitable dialog command to click a button.

Need help.

Tried many DIALOG Commands like EXECUTE, SELECT, SET. nothing worked to click a button when the dialog box is open already.

Comment: A Dialog windows' intended use case is to interface with the user. If you want automate a task (=no user interaction), using a dialog is the wrong approach in the first place. What exactly do you want to achieve?